# jWYSIWYG in jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jwysiwyg

It seems there's an issue with the editor when you try to use it inside a dialog.

I've tested my application and in the normal page (main html) everything works well. When I put my AJAX result in the main html, I still have the editor, even in the accordion. But when I put the accordion AJAX result with the editor in the dialog, it breaks. The buttons are visible, but my text isn't there and I can't type anything in it.

Some of the code:

**Javascript: The Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/mvc/pi/report/chapters',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
       candidateId : id,
       projectId : projectId
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#report').html(data);
        $("textarea").wysiwyg();
    }
});
```

**HTML-result of the AJAX-call**

```
    <div id="contentInput">
    <form name="chapterList" id="contentInputForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="projectId" value="<?= $this->projectId; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="candidateId" value="<?= $this->candidateId; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="img" id="imgInput">
    <div class="box-rounded">
        <ul>
            <li><?=$this->translate('First name')?>: <?= (is_object($this->candidate) ? $this->candidate->getUser()->getFirstName() : ''); ?></li>
            <li><?=$this->translate('Last name')?>: <?= (is_object($this->candidate) ? $this->candidate->getUser()->getLastName() : ''); ?></li>
            <li><?=$this->translate('Match')?>: <?= (is_object($this->candidate) ? $this->candidate->getCandidateMatch() : ''); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Grafiek</a></h3>
    <div id="grafiek"></div>
    <h3><a href="#">Keywords</a></h3>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="rw input autowidth">
                <label class="labeled-input">
                    <input class="labeled-input" type="text" name="keyword" value="<?= (is_object($this->candidate) ? $this->candidate->getKeywords() : ''); ?>" />
                    <span class="value visible"><?= (strlen((string) $this->candidate->getKeywords()) > 0 ? '' : 'Keywords'); ?></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
<?php foreach($this->chapters as $chapter): ?>
        <h3><a href="#"><?= $chapter['name']; ?></a></h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="active_<?= $chapter['id']; ?>"><?= $this->translate('Show in Report'); ?></label> <input name="active_<?= $chapter['id']; ?>" type="checkbox" <?= ($chapter['active'] ? 'checked' : ''); ?>>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <textarea id="chapter_<?= $chapter['id']; ?>" rows="20" cols="70" name="chapter_<?= $chapter['id']; ?>"><?= (isset($chapter['content']) ? $chapter['content'] : ''); ?></textarea>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: The code has been added to the question.